# script in sub collapsible fire twice when clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, collapsable

I get a little mad because i do not find the hint:
I ve a collapsible set, wich is created dynamic from a database, which shows me some dates.
Then i want to fill content to the collapsibles, which should be also a collapsible(this present some details, of the specific day)
This content is coming of another ajaxcall (getDaydata(gotDate)) which is working.
But if i click to expand the subset (the dateget-content-collapsible class) the ajax call is fired twice, and the append kills the layout.
So how can i prevent this second event to be fired up?
Thanks for the help.
Klaus

```
$('#home').live('pagebeforecreate',function(event, ui){
countview = 7;
getPersons(countview);
});

getPersons(countview);
});
$('.dateget-headline').live('expand', function(){
var str=this.id;
var gotDate=str.substring (8,18);
getDaydata(gotDate);
});

function getPersons(countstand)
{
$.ajax({
url: 'fllist1.php',
 type: 'GET',
 data: {countitems: countstand},
 dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {

 $.each(data, function(i,Person)
    {
    $('<div/>', {
   'id': 'dateget-'+Person.dataget+'-collapsible',
   'data-role':'collapsible',
   'class':'dateget-headline',
   'data-collapsed':'true',
    }).appendTo('#main-content-list');
    $('#dateget-'+Person.dataget+'-collapsible').html('<h5>'+ Person.dataget +'</h5>');   
 $('.datelist').collapsible();
//create a new collapsible set inside the collabsible

$('<div/>', {
'id': 'dateget-'+Person.dataget+'-collapsible-set',
 'data-role':'collapsible-set',
'class':'dateget-content-collapsible-set',
'data-theme':'c',
'data-content-theme':'d',
}).appendTo('#dateget-'+Person.dataget+'-collapsible');
$('.dateget-headline').collapsible();
});
}
});
};

 function getDaydata(gotDate){
 var gotDate=getDaydata.arguments[0];
 $.ajax({
 url: 'getDatedetails.php',
 type: 'GET',
 data: 'detailday=' + gotDate,
dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(i,Fldet){

    $('<div/>', {
    'id': 'dateget-'+Fldet.id+'-collapsible',
    'data-role':'collapsible',
    'class':'dateget-content-collapsible',
    'data-collapsed':'true',
     }).appendTo('#dateget-'+gotDate+'-collapsible-set');
   $('#dateget-'+Fldet.id+'-       collapsible').html('<h1>'+Fldet.reg+'</h1>'+Fldet.call+Fldet.arrtt+Fldet.dept );

});
$('.dateget-content-collapsible').collapsible();
},

}
});
};
```

here you can see the script in action: http://nixnutz.info/lowimobil2.php

Answer (score 0):

did you try `event.preventDefault();`?
the collapsible content events you can find [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible-events.html)